# SAML Single logout - Keycloak and Mattermost integration

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, logout, keycloak, mattermost

I configured single sign on SAML between mattermost and keycloak but we have problem during single logout. When I called url for logout I get response from mattermost api that logout was success. But after open mattermost url for login I can login without username and password. When I close and open browser after logout everything is fine and keycloak ask for username and password. I need scenario for keycloak ask user and pass without closing browser after logout.

During logout process firstly I called url defined in keycloak documentation

```
https://keycloak-app/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/logout?redirect_uri=https://mattermost-app/login/sso/saml
```

I get response from mattermost api but I'm not redirect to login site. I must go to login manually

```
{"status":"OK"}
```

Configuration in keycloak:

```
Force Post binding: Enable
Front Channel Logout: Enable
Logout Service POST biding URL: https//:mattermost-app/api/v4/users/logout
Logout Service Redirect Binding URL: https://mattermost-app/login/sso/saml
```

I hope I wrote enough information for explain my problem. Thank for help

Comment: Do you use some keycloak adapter in your application?

Comment: We don't have custom application and probably there is no choice add some custom stuff to mattermost. It's only integration between default mattermost and keycloak installation. Both app are behind apache proxy

Comment: @e5341: can you provide your i am also facing same problem

Comment: any reasons for mixing OpenID Connect and SAML URLs on your setup?